Clean Install on SSD while the HDD is still plug in
I want to do a clean install on my SSD. Currently, I have Windows 11 both on my SSD and HDD. But, I boot from the SSD now.
I read that you must unplug your hard drive first before doing a clean install bcs Windows could get confused (?). But, I can’t unplug my hard drive, I have to pry my laptop open and I can’t do it.
What precaution should I take to avoid bad things that could happen if I do a clean install without unplugging my HDD? Would my laptop doomed if I don’t unplug my HDD first? (I read that your system reserved can end up on your HDD instead of SSD)
I also saw a tutorial that delete the drive partitions first and install it on the unallocated space, but I also saw another tutorial that just chooses the primary partition (without deleting all the partitions first). What is the outcome difference between those two?

Go into the BIOS & disable it?
